# GDB Disassembler shows assembly code - but in a different way than I expected

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, nasm

I recently started using the gdb disassembler, and wanted to see how it really displays the assembly code, is it logical or not (Tried debugging a C program, a function that calculates the length of a linked-list).

This is the C code (Not mine, have to credit [this site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/linked_list_program_in_c.htm)):

```
int length() {
   int length = 0;
   struct node *current;
    
   for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
      length++;
   }
    
   return length;
}
```

Compiled:

```
gcc linkedlist.c -o linkedlist
```

This is the resulting disassemble (intel-flavored):

```
   0x00000000000012a8 <+0>: endbr64 
   0x00000000000012ac <+4>: push   rbp
   0x00000000000012ad <+5>: mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00000000000012b0 <+8>: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x0
   0x00000000000012b7 <+15>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x2d5a]        # 0x4018 <head>
   0x00000000000012be <+22>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x00000000000012c2 <+26>:    jmp    0x12d4 <length+44>
   0x00000000000012c4 <+28>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x1
   0x00000000000012c8 <+32>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
   0x00000000000012cc <+36>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rax+0x8]
   0x00000000000012d0 <+40>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
   0x00000000000012d4 <+44>:    cmp    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
   0x00000000000012d9 <+49>:    jne    0x12c4 <length+28>
   0x00000000000012db <+51>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
   0x00000000000012de <+54>:    pop    rbp
   0x00000000000012df <+55>:    ret
```

What really bothers me, which is a little thing that I notice, maybe you notice more, is that it is not the type of assembly code I was being taught. I remember teachers/professors saying over and over again: "Don't use mov ,0x0, just xor , "

But here, inside it does:
`DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x0`

Which I assume is the initialization of the variable `int length = 0;`

My questions are, why it does not show the most effective code? and if it cannot do that (Probably everything is not perfect) - then why it does not know to detect initialization of the number `0` and do the xor operation instead of the mov (automatically), does that really matter performance (If it does, by what factor?)

Maybe there are more lines that could've been replaces/disregarded at all, but I as a beginner do not notice them, but this specific one I did.. any explanation?

Comment: How did you compile the code? Did you add an optimization flag, like `-O2`?

Comment: @ssbssa no, I didnt think it was important for the question I will update how I compiled the C program

Comment: If you are zeroing a memory location, how would that XOR look like? [And is that a valid combination of arguments?](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/xor) (look for "However..")

Comment: Well, if you want the resulting executable to have good performance, you need to add an optimization flag.

Comment: `xor` as a zeroing idiom only works on registers, as it needs a `xor` with itself. Explicit memory operands cannot be both operands of a `xor`. (However, `and` with 0 is a shorter way of zero-initialising memory than `mov`.)

Comment: @ssbssa When I do compile with `-O2` it shows me a completely different shorter code with a xorring of a variable, awesome! Thank you!

Comment: GDB shows you the code that's there.  Your phrasing is very strange, like you want GDB to show you optimized code even though that's not what you told GCC to make.  I assume that's not what you meant.  If you just want to look at compiler output, there are easier ways, e.g. [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) using `gcc -O2 -S` or https://godbolt.org/

Comment: BTW, if you don't already have a `0` in a register, `mov [mem], 0` *is* a decent choice for zeroing memory, even though it means using a large immediate zero.  If you want to zero more than a single qword, often worth zeroing an XMM register, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, gcc is compiling with the `-O0` option enabled as default. It generates the code exactly as it is written in the source file, without any optimizations. The compiler can optimize the code having many possible options as in the example below:

```
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
};

int length(struct node *head) {
   int length = 0;
   struct node *current;
    
   for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
      length++;
   }
    
   return length;
}

int __attribute__((optimize("-O3"))) length1(struct node *head) {
   int length = 0;
   struct node *current;
    
   for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
      length++;
   }
    
   return length;
}

int __attribute__((optimize("-Os"))) length2(struct node *head) {
   int length = 0;
   struct node *current;
    
   for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
      length++;
   }
    
   return length;
}

int __attribute__((optimize("-Og"))) length3(struct node *head) {
   int length = 0;
   struct node *current;
    
   for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
      length++;
   }
    
   return length;
}
```

and the code

```
length:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        add     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-16]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
.L2:
        cmp     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], 0
        jne     .L3
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        pop     rbp
        ret
length1:
        xor     eax, eax
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .L8
.L7:
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        add     eax, 1
        test    rdi, rdi
        jne     .L7
        ret
.L8:
        ret
length2:
        xor     eax, eax
.L12:
        test    rdi, rdi
        je      .L14
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        inc     eax
        jmp     .L12
.L14:
        ret
length3:
        mov     eax, 0
        jmp     .L16
.L17:
        add     eax, 1
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rdi]
.L16:
        test    rdi, rdi
        jne     .L17
        ret
```